# Нужно отменить автоисправление { code(); } в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2015

**Когда я пишу код, Visual Studio сам после } исправляет все скобки с переносом на другую строку.**

```
if (1) {
  code();
}
```

**VS исправляет код (C#) на:**

```
if (1) 
{
  code();
}
```

**Да, это важно, место не экономится.**

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос? Из написанного не ясно, какой вариант вы хотите получить.

Comment: Это соглашения о написании кода принятые для платформы .net. Если вы планируете дальше развиваться в этом направлении, то придётся привыкать.

Comment: Но если прям уж ну очень хочется, то `Tools` => `Options` => `Text Editor` => `C#` => `Code Style` => `Formating` => `New Lines`

Comment: Если нужно экономить место, то пишите так: `if (1) code();` Вообще в одну строчку

Comment: "Да, это важно, место не экономится." - если вы не хотите писать в стиле BrainFuck, то экономить место совсем не следует, а следует наоборот даже вставлять специально пустые строки между смысловыми блоками кода. По статистике код чаще читают чем пишут, а потому сверхважна читабельность кода, да, вы это и сами скоро поймете, если начтете писать более-менее серьезный большой проект.